# Using Texture Atlasing and EaselJs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs

I know EaselJS has an awesome way of managing their sprites, but is it even possible to make it easier?

The following link convinced me to use texture atlasing : http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/09/17/building-an-html5-game-dont-shrug-off-atlases/

Few pointers why I want this so badly :

- Flash CS6 Generate Spritesheet feature creates the TextureAtlas ready for use
- Improves load time
- Saves bandwidth
- Better Dev time

I have no idea how to kick start this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's much you need to do to use 'texture atlases' with EaselJS (which are, btw, despite the linked author's disclaimers, pretty much identical to sprite sheets).  On any Bitmap you create in EaselJS, you set a source image and a source rectangle on that image.  I'm using about three source images to provide 100+ bitmap elements for my little app.

Comment: Exactly. EaselJS also supports a SpriteSheet format, which can optionally be output using Zoë (http://createjs.com/zoe).

Comment: Thanks guys, if one of you guys can post it as an answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'll expand on my comment a little.

When you create a display element in EaselJS, you give it a source image:

```
srcImage = new Image();
srcImage.src = "http://whatever.com/image.png";
...
sprite1 = new Bitmap(srcImage);
```

By default, the instance of the Bitmap is the whole image.  However, you can pinpoint the Bitmap down to a region of that image.  For instance, suppose the image contains a row of 32x32 tiles:

```
sprites = [];
for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
  sprites[i] = new Bitmap(srcImage);
  sprites[i].sourceRect = { x:i*32, y:0, width:32, height:32 };
}
```

You've now got eight sprites, each referring to a different 32x32 region of the source image.

You can also change it dynamically:

```
sprCursor = new Bitmap(srcImage);
sprCursor.sourceRect = ( x:0, y:0, width:32, height:32 };
...
if(cursorOverButton) {
  sprCursor.sourceRect = { x:32, y:0, width:32, height:32 };
  // or more efficiently, sprCursor.sourceRect.x = 32;
}
```

I imagine that's pretty much how EaselJS works behind the scenes to handle animated sprites.